# How to turn java game code into an android application to play on a phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Heyyy,

I was recommended this site by a friend who does Computer Science and he said it was the place to go to.

I have the following code for a 'Java' breakout (brickbreaker) game:

http://pastebin.com/fN8WBKpW

A group I am working in needs this code to run as an application on an android device so we can do surveys on it for our work project.

I know little about 'Java code' but one of the guys in our group has android studio + eclipse and has run it on his computer using one of the programs. He doesn't know how to get this code to be an application that he can transfer on to his phone.

If anyone can help us it would be much appreciated.

thankyouuu
xx

Comment: You'd have to rewrite parts of it -- Android doesn't use Swing (JFrame UI stuff).

Comment: Please also post the code (as text) here.

Answer (score 0):

Android operates slightly differently than Pure Java. If you want your application to work natively on android, you are going to have to use android specific libraries  and classes.